# What is the return type of the built-in assignment operator?

Tags: c++, reference, assignment-operator, dereference, lvalue

I am just starting C++. I am a bit confused about the return type of assignment and dereference operator. I am following the book C++ Primer. At various occasions, the author says that the return type of assignment operator is reference to the type of left hand operand but later on, he says that the return type is the type of the left hand operand. I have referred C++11 Standard Sec. 5.17, where the return type is described as "lvalue referring to left hand operand".

Similarly, I can't figure out whether dereference returns the pointed-to object or the reference to the object.

Are these statements equivalent? If so, then how?

Comment: Plz everyone take note. thanks for all the replies but i did not mean to ask about operator overloading. i m not there yet, i was just asking about assignment operation built in the language.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The standard correctly defines the return type of an assignment operator.
Actually, the assignment operation itself doesn't depend on the return value - that's why the return type isn't straightforward to understanding.

The return type is important for chaining operations.
Consider the following construction: `a = b = c;`. This should be equal to `a = (b = c)`, i.e. `c` should be assigned into `b` and `b` into `a`. Rewrite this as `a.operator=(b.operator=(c))`. In order for the assignment into `a` to work correctly the return type of `b.operator=(c)` must be reference to the inner assignment result (it will work with copy too but that's just an unnecessary overhead).

The dereference operator return type depends on your inner logic, define it in the way that suits your needs.

Comment: "The standard correctly defines the return type of an assignment operator" - how?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore as OP has quoted: *C++11 Standard Sec. 5.17, where the return type is described as "lvalue referring to left hand operand".*

Comment: This last comment is already more useful than the whole answer.

Comment: I couldn't help to notice the level of support that last comment got. I find it's a bit disappointing that many people find the shallow formal writeoff more useful than the detailed answer that explains the actual reasoning. And yes, technically you can have an assignment operator that returns value instead of reference.

Comment: Why not a `const &` by the way ? Could that be a problem for some use ?

Comment: @cassepipe As I understand it, the assignment operator returns a non-const reference because in the calling code, you're by definition already assigning to this object and hence must already be using a non-const reference to the object.
This avoids the potential breakage of introducing 'const' to those operations.

Comment: Chaining Works Without Reference: Returning a copy from operator= still allows for chaining assignments (like a = b = c), as the operator= will return a temporary object (a copy of the assigned object), which can then be used in subsequent assignments. However, this involves creating and destroying temporary objects, which might incur a performance overhead, especially if these operations are expensive for the class in question.

Answer (score 13):

They can both be anything, but *usually* `operator =` returns the current object by reference, i.e.

```
A& A::operator = ( ... )
{
   return *this;
}
```

And yes, "reference to the type of left hand operand" and "lvalue referring to left hand operand" mean the same thing.

The dereference operator can have basically any return type. It mostly depends on the logic of the program, because you're overloading the operator that applies to an object, not to a pointer to the object. Usually, this is used for smart pointers, or iterators, and return the object they wrap around:

```
struct smart_ptr
{
   T* innerPtr;
   T* smart_ptr::operator* ()
   {
      return innerPtr;
   }
}

smart_ptr p; 
T* x = *p;
```

Comment: Can you please expand on the "lvalue referring to left hand operand" meaning the same as "reference to the type of left hand operand". Is reference an lvalue?

Comment: @user2148032 yes, a reference is an lvalue. The left hand operand is the object itself (because `x = y` has the left hand operand `x`).

Answer (score 2):

I have seen similar issues, but I guess it would be best to use

```
X& X::operator=(const X&);
```

Using this, you will be able to reuse the object in a chain-assignment.

Answer (score 0):

**Chaining Works Without Reference:**
Returning a copy from operator= still allows for chaining assignments (like a = b = c), as the operator= will return a temporary object (a copy of the assigned object), which can then be used in subsequent assignments. However, this involves creating and destroying temporary objects, which might incur a performance overhead, especially if these operations are expensive for the class in question.

**As Scott Meyers mentioned in his Effective C++ book :**

The way this is implemented is that assignment returns a reference to
its left-hand argument, and **that’s the convention** you should follow
when you implement assignment operators for your classes. This is only a convention; code that doesn’t follow it will compile. However,
the convention is followed by all the built-in types as well as by
all the types in (or soon to be in — see Item 54) the standard library
(e.g., string, vector, complex, tr1::shared_ptr, etc.). **Unless you have a good reason for doing things differently, don’t.**

Code below works just fine!

```
#include <iostream>
class Rational {
public:
    // ctor is deliberately not explicit; allows implicit int-to-Rational conversions
    Rational(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1)
    {

        this->m_numerator = numerator;
        this->m_denominator = denominator;
    }
    int numerator() const  // accessors for numerator 
    {

        return this->m_numerator;
    }
    int denominator() const // accessors for denominator 
    {

        return this->m_denominator;

    }
    Rational operator=(const Rational& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "operator=(const Rational& rhs)\n";
        this->m_numerator = rhs.m_numerator;
        this->m_denominator = rhs.m_denominator;
        return *this;
    }
    
    private:
    int m_numerator{};
    int m_denominator{};
};

int main()
{
    Rational a(1, 2);
    Rational b(3, 4);
    Rational c(5, 6);
    a = b = c; //  a.operator=(b.operator=(c));
}
```