# Return type for the assignment operator

Tags: c++, class, c++11

What is the difference between an operator defined with its class name:

```
class RefObj {
public:
    RefObj &operator=(const RefObj &) { return *this; }
private:
    int m_Counter = 0;
};
```

and an operator with void:

```
template<class T> class SmartPtr {
public:
    void operator=(T* pointer) { m_SmartPtr = pointer; }
private:
    T* m_SmartPtr;
}
```

When should I use the first one and when should I use the second one?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29#Return_value_of_overloaded_assignment_operator

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is return type of assignment operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292892/what-is-return-type-of-assignment-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first version allows to do further operations on the returned object in *one line* as in

```
(refobj = a).do_something();
```

When you don't return a reference to the object, this is not possible. You may think this is silly, but think about output operators.

```
void operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Obj1 &obj1);
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Obj2 &obj2);

Obj1 obj1;
Obj2 obj2;
std::cout << obj1 << '\t' << obj1 << std::endl;  // compiler error
//               ^^^^ '<<' can't operate on void
std::cout << obj2 << '\t' << obj2 << std::endl;  // works!
//               ^^^^ return type is std::ostream, '<<' work on that
```

Given that returning a reference is really cheap, I recommend to always return one. This will save you the pain of searching for strange bugs where otherwise perfectly sane syntax will break your code.

Comment: @Eiron does this answer your question, or did I get you wrong?