# whats the return type of assignment operator?

Tags: c++, c, return-type, assignment-operator

I know it returns whatever is on left side. So in case of character assignment we would get a character and in case of int assignment we would get a int type.

Isn't there a fix datatype of assignment operator?

Comment: it depends on the type. the `operator=` of some class `Foo` has little to nothing in common with the `operator=` of some other type `Bar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is return type of assignment operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292892/what-is-return-type-of-assignment-operator)

Comment: it is `C` or `C++`? They both are different languages. My answer below is for C.

Comment: Why not include some more languages?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16, *Assignment operators* (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] An
>   assignment expression has the **value of the left operand after the assignment**, but is not
>   an lvalue. The **type of an assignment expression is the type the left operand would have
>   after lvalue conversion**.

Answer (score 2):

**In C++**:

The built-in assignment operator returns a reference, or more precisely, an assignment expression is an lvalue.

Returning a reference is also required for an item in a standard collection.

Apart from that you can define an assignment operator for a class type, with any return type you want, including `void` (which otherwise IMHO would have been preferable).

**In C**:
In C there are no user defined assignment operators, and an assignment expression is an rvalue. I.e., in C you can't do `(a = b) = c` that you can do in C++. Which IMHO is an advantage.

Comment: I'm a fan of the `void` return type for the user-defined assignment operator. +1