# why if(x=0) is evaluates to false?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements

everyone.

```
int x{};
if (x = 0) 
    std::cout << "condition true";
else
    std::cout << "condition false";
```

I didnt understand why x=0 evaluates to boolean false and executing "condition false". x=0 is an assignment,and x gets value of 0 so why it doesnt evaluate to true ?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be true?

Comment: if you write `x = 1` it'll yield `true`. This is basically the same for every other number. `0` is the numeric representation of `false`

Comment: Do you expect assignments to return a value that indicates "successfull assignment" or something?

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and many related SO questions. Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and also refer to [what is return type of assignment operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292892/what-is-return-type-of-assignment-operator)

Comment: *"x gets value of 0 so why it doesnt evaluate to true ?"* It does not evaluate to `true` **because** `x` gets the value 0. *Do you see why it helps to explain your reasoning? The answer to "why" is "because". However, if you explain your reasoning in greater detail, someone might be able to pick out the step where your reasoning goes off course.*

Comment: Zero values in C++ are *falsy*.  Non-zero values in C++ are *truthy*.

Answer (score 12):

The value of `x=0` is that of `x` after the assignment. `0` is the only integer that when converted to `bool` is `false`.

Comment: okay so even = is an operator, x=2 is not an expression, right ?

Comment: @smalcakmak why do you think so? It is an expression and the value of the expression `x=2` is `2`